# Cannot install two apps at a time in android

Tags: android, ios, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am having two apps which are on my playstore(android) and appstore(ios) but you can install only one app at a time.Both the apps cannot be installed at sametime in android.While in ios it does allows to install both the apps at sametime.What could be the issue? Thank you.

Comment: That's odd. Can you share links to your apps on the play store?

Comment: @Chinmay can you elaborate the issue or give any logs of the error that you are getting from playstore.

Comment: @npk 1)https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.id8sbm.entwine
2)https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sis.tracko

Comment: @Syn3sthete it says cannot install app.Please try again.

Comment: @Chinmay Google Play is not providing necessary details on the user side. If you haven't received any email/notification from Google, you should contact the support team.